# SQL double foreign key in single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a sql beginner. I'm creating a DB to track student's enrolls in schools.

I created the first 3 tables Students, Schools and Classes (DB have to track in which class a student is) using:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
        studId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
        name varchar(20),
        surname varchar(20),
        birthDate date,
        birthPlace varchar(40)
    );

CREATE TABLE Schools (
    schId varchar(20) NOT NULL primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    province char(2),
    region varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Classes (
    classId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    schId varchar(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (schId) REFERENCES Schools(schId),
    PRIMARY KEY (classId, schId),
    name varchar(5),
    course varchar(20),
    option varchar(20)
);
```

Now, I need a Enroll table but this causes an error:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolls(
    studId int,
    schId varchar(20),
    classId varchar(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (schId) REFERENCES Schools(schId),
    FOREIGN KEY (studId) REFERENCES Students(studId),
    FOREIGN KEY (classId) REFERENCES Classes(classId),
    PRIMARY KEY(studId, schId, classId)
);
```

I suppose because classId is a primary key with schId in Classes table.

How can I fix?

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table studentsdb.enrolls (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Please, post the error message.

Comment: ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `studentsdb`.`enrolls` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: At first glance  `schId varchar(20)` has to be NULL also

Comment: At second glance `classId varchar(20)` has to be an `int`, just like in the referenced table.

Comment: At third glance option is a reserved word

Comment: At forth glance, having both `schId` in `classes` and `enroles` might be wrong, depending on what `schId` is, since an entry in `enroles` would then have 2 `schId`'s, one from `classes`, and one from `enroles` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run below code

Tried on sqlfiddle working successfully. Changes marked.

Sqlfiddle link - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7dd7/1/0

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
        studId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
        name varchar(20),
        surname varchar(20),
        birthDate date,
        birthPlace varchar(40)
    );

CREATE TABLE Schools (
    schId varchar(20) NOT NULL primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    province char(2),
    region varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Classes (
    classId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    schId varchar(20),
    name varchar(5),
    course varchar(20),
    option_a varchar(20), -- not accepting column name "option"
  FOREIGN KEY (schId) REFERENCES Schools(schId),
  PRIMARY KEY (classId, schId)
);


CREATE TABLE Enrolls(
    studId int,
    schId varchar(20),
    classId int, --changed data type to int i think due to which issue was coming also suggested in other answers.
    FOREIGN KEY (schId) REFERENCES Schools(schId),
    FOREIGN KEY (studId) REFERENCES Students(studId),
    FOREIGN KEY (classId) REFERENCES Classes(classId),
    PRIMARY KEY(studId, schId, classId)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that'll resolve the error

Your `classID` in table `Enrolls` is of type `varchar(20)` and in table `Classes` is of type `int`.

Make sure they both have the same type.
Error will gone!!